# Async/wait function is blocking other UI controller in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to send 30 mails when a user clicks on button. I just want to shoot mails without depending on mail sending request response. I am looping through all the obj sending async requests to send mails, but the problem is when I click on UI some other request it is waiting to complete the mail-sending request even from UI request is cancel

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> SendBulkEmails(List<EmailObj> req)
{
    //this is for simply when it hit first just  loop all send even if user cancle the request ui not  depend any output of this 
    dynamic jsonData = new ExpandoObject();
    jsonData.status = "success";
    List<Task> allTask = new List<Task>();
    foreach (EmailObj obj in req)
    {                
        await SendNotification(obj.to,obj.message).ConfigureAwait(false);    
    }
      
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am using .NET 4.5, I want to send these mail without depending on their response, and if a user clicks for other request it should not wait to complete these.

Comment: Have you tried Task Parallel Library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl

Comment: @maxspan        will it work with async mehtod in .net 4.5 for parallel ?  no , i have not

Comment: Sorry TPL is only used for running parallel operation. What you are looking for is fire and forget solution.

Comment: Fire-and-forget is dangerous. I recommend a [proper distributed system](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary    thanks for reply , i have read your blog , as fresher i started reading async await from your blog so thanks for that. i sound silly & wrong but is there any work around to just handle this situation ,in site only this functionality needed.

Comment: If you want to handle cancellation, add a `CancellationToken` parameter to your controller endpoint and observe it in your `SendNotification` method

Comment: How are you calling this method from the client? Show relevant code

Comment: @gaurav: You're trying to make ASP.NET do something no web host is designed to do, so there's no simple solution. Unless you outsource it, e.g , use an api for bulk email like SendGrid.

Answer (score 0):

To send emails asynchronously without waiting for their responses and without blocking other user requests, you can use `Task.WhenAll` to execute all the email sending tasks concurrently.

```
List<Task> emailSendingTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (EmailObj obj in req)
{
    // Start the email sending task and add it to the list
    emailSendingTasks.Add(SendNotification(obj.to, obj.message));
}

await Task.WhenAll(emailSendingTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

By adding the email sending tasks to the `emailSendingTasks` list and then using `Task.WhenAll`, all the email sending tasks will be started concurrently. It won't wait for their completion, and it won't block other user requests.